# Get The Current Ratting of AJAX Rating Control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have a Rating control in ASP.NET page. on Button Click on client Side i need to validate the Current Rating of Rating value if greater than 0 ... but i am unable to get the rating value as browser render the Rating Control as DIV and then anchor tag inside the div.

My code is

```
 var errorRating = $("#rateReviewArr").get_Rating();
 var errorRating2 = $("#rateReviewArr")._currentRating;
```

but both of the lines didnt get the Current Rating of Rating Control.

Comment: waht is the rating plugin you used?

Comment: this is AJAX Control Toolkit Rating control 3.0